# C# (WinForms) mousedownevents for axShockwaveFlash object and windowsmediaplayer

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to handle mousedownevents for axShockwaveFlash object and windowsmediaplayer. wmp does have a custom mousedown event:

```
wmp_MouseDownEvent(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_MouseDownEvent e)
```

but I don't know how to use it (cant find any explanation), I tried:

```
 if (e.nButton == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
        }
```

But that didnt work. 
I prefer a way for handle mousedown events for the axShockwaveFlash object though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, after ReleaseCapture();

```
Message msg = new Message();
msg.HWnd = Handle;
msg.Msg = WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN;
msg.WParam = HT_CAPTION;
msg.LParam = 0;
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.PreProcessControlMessage(ref msg);
```

Comment: No I get an error at the if statement, but what about the shockwaveflash object? I am going to take a look at a global mouse hook, that should do that trick

Comment: Well, you hadn't specified where exactly you get the error and the error itself!

Comment: yeah mainly because I was inclined to not use wmp in my final build, thanks anyway